# I'm getting uncaught runtime error of not existing data

Tags: javascript, css, strapi, scss-mixins

I'm getting this uncaught runtime error while trying to access data of my product[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEHl9.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Product.scss";

const Product = ({ data, id }) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
        <div
            className="product-card"
            onClick={() => navigate("/product/" + id)}
        >
            <div className="thumbnail">
                <img
                    src={
                        process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_URL +
                        this.data.image.data[0].attributes.url
                    }
                />
            </div>
            <div className="prod-details">
                <span className="name">{data.title}</span>
                <span className="price">&#8377;{data.price}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Product;
```

It shows error while fetching the data above

[this is the error that is shown after i start npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdaUT.png)

i tried changing to this.data it still doesnt work.

Comment: You shouldn't use 'this.' for it. Can you copy/paste your error instead of linking out?

Comment: @Fata1Err0r is correct. The error you are encountering is due to the incorrect usage of "this" keyword inside a functional component in React. In functional components, you don't need to use this to access props.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. In this case, you wouldn't use 'this.' for it. If you can just copy/paste your error instead, that'd be helpful because I'm not going to link out of this site. I'd check the data coming in also. Here's example for that:

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Product.scss";

const Product = ({ data, id }) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    if (!data) {
        // Handle case when data is missing or undefined
        return null; // or render a placeholder/error message
    }

    return (
        <div className="product-card" onClick={() => navigate("/product/" + id)}>
            <div className="thumbnail">
                <img
                    src={
                        process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_URL +
                        (data.image?.data[0]?.attributes?.url || "")
                    }
                    alt={data.title || "Product Image"}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="prod-details">
                <span className="name">{data.title}</span>
                <span className="price">&#8377;{data.price}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Product;
```